# Icon not working properly

Tags: react-native, header, icons, react-native-ios

I added an Icon to my Header with the code below:

```
<Header
 rightComponent = {<Icon name = 'login' color = 'white' size = {23} onPress ={() => console.log('pressed')}/>
/>
```

When I simulate it an press the Icon nothing shows up in the console. 
This is what the documentation says to do so I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: react-native-vector-icons/dist/Entypo, the Icon shows up fine. It's just that when I press it to console logs nothing when it should log 'pressed'.

Comment: Is that a direct copy of your current code? You are missing a bracket (`}`) to close the the `rightComponent` prop. Although I'm not sure if that would cause your issue if you're saying that the Icon renders fine.

Comment: No it is not a direct copy. I have the bracket in my current code.

Comment: I have it in my headerBackground. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Do you need to use the [Icon.Button Component](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/blob/45e86173761c0c2fbf94faba163e636fdcc5e12f/README.md#iconbutton-component) instead?

Comment: I tried it and it shows up fine but still cannot log to the console when pressed.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by in your headerBackground?